# Windows batch script to copy newest files with partial names

Tags: batch-file, backup, batch-rename

I have a backup program that saves `.bak` files into a folder which it rotates on a weekly basis automatically.

The files are given given names like this:

```
DB_Live_19052015.bak
DB_Test_19052015.bak
DB_Live_18052015.bak
DB_Test_18052015.bak
```

The backup program doesn't allow me to edit these names and I actually don't want it to.

What I do need is to be able to copy the newest file of each set `DB_Live_XXXXXXXX.bak` & `DB_Test_XXXXXXXX.bak` and rename them to drop the date so I end up with files like this for `DR`:

```
dr/DB_Live.bak
dr/DB_Test.bak
```

This would be overwritten each time the script was run.

No I can copy the latest file in a folder and rename it using scripting but I cannot get my head round how to

- A. get the set of latest files (multiple)
- B. rename these files based on their original names to drop only the on the end.

What I am expecting to have to do is the following:

1. copy the latest files to a `dr` folder
2. get the file names for each file
3. rename the files and overwrite anything already there with that name

I'm going to be adding this scripting into the backup program so it runs when the backup has finished.

The reason for these files is so I can `RSYNC` them off site without sending the whole file every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=%cd%\source"
    set "target=%cd%\target"

    for %%a in (DB_Live DB_Test) do (
        set "first=1"
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('
            dir /a-d /tw /o-d /b "%source%\%%a_*.bak"
        ') do if defined first (
            set "first="
            copy /b /y "%source%\%%~b" "%target%\%%a%%~xb"
        )
    )
```

For each set of files, execute a `dir` command in reverse modified date order. In this list the first file is the last modified. Copy this file to the target overwritting the existing file (if present).

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I've successfully added this to BackupAssist as a post successful backup script to run and it tested well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo.>%temp%\tempone.txt
if not exist dr md dr
if not exist dblive md dblive
if not exist dbtest md dbtest
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%I in (*) do (
set red=%%I
set blue=!red:~0,7!
if "!blue!"=="DB_Live" copy /y !red! dblive>nul
if "!blue!"=="DB_Test" copy /y !red! dbtest>nul
)
pushd %cd%
cd dblive
for %%I in (*) do (
set green=%%I
set green=!green:DB_Live_=!
set green=!green:.bak=!
echo !green! >>%temp%\tempone.txt
)
set max=0
for /f %%x in (%temp%\tempone.txt) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
echo the latest dblive file is DB_Live_!max!.bak--copied to dr folder
set dblatest=DB_Live_!max!.bak
copy /y !dblatest! %temp%>nul
popd
copy /y %temp%\!dblatest! dr>nul
::same for dbtest
pushd %cd%
cd dbtest
for %%I in (*) do (
set green=%%I
set green=!green:DB_Test_=!
set green=!green:.bak=!
echo !green! >>%temp%\temptwo.txt
)
set max=0
for /f %%x in (%temp%\temptwo.txt) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
echo the latest dbtest file is DB_Test_!max!.bak--copied to dr folder
set dblatest=DB_Test_!max!.bak
copy /y !dblatest! %temp%>nul
popd
copy /y %temp%\!dblatest! dr>nul
::rename both files
pushd %cd%
cd dr
ren DB_Live_* DB_Live.bak
if %errorlevel%==0 echo renamed dblive
ren DB_Test_* DB_Test.bak 
if %errorlevel%==0 echo renamed dbtest
pause
```

put in the same folder as the .bak files. hope this helps!